# Capabilities issue with Selenium webdrive support version 4.17 in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, selenium4

I have upgraded Selenium WebDriver from 4.7 to 4.17.

but while launching Chrome, I got the below error message:

```
Capabilities = {{
  "message": "session not created exception: Missing or invalid capabilities\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19045 x86_64)"
}}
```

I tried to downgrade package from 4.17 to 4.10 sequentially but facing same error with all versions.

It is working fine with 4.9 version.

Please let me know if have any suggestions to resolve this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why are you downgrading from version 4.7 to 4.17?

Comment: Update chromedriver, update Your local browser, check if all of capabilities used by You in code are supported for latest versions of chromedriver https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities - You can try to remove Your capabilities from driver initialization code 1 by 1 to check which is causing problems eventually. In nuget manager You should have at least 2 packages - Selenium.WebDriver and Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver - make sure You have updated them all

Comment: @IceCode I downgraded versions just for testing purpose, to know on which version its working.

Comment: same here, 

selenium                  4.17.2               ------------------------

chromedriver-121.0.6167.184-1.fc39.x86_64    ------------------------


google-chrome-stable-121.0.6167.184-1.x86_64    ------------------------

Comment: This happens also on linux, also with selenium 4.18

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to Environment variable>>System variable>>Path>>Initially remove old chrome exe path first

2.Go to C: driver Program Files >> bin >> Remove old chrome driver folder

3.Go to Environment variable>>System variable>>Path>> Add new path as (C:\Program Files(X86)\Google\Chrome\Application)

CC:@Abhijeet Unde